# Exporting multiple shapefile layers from QGIS3 to one KMZ file

Tags: qgis-3, export, kmz

I have a .KMZ file which contains several separate layers which each contain important information, some are polygons, lines and points. When I import this into QGIS3 it displays separate KMZ layers organised into a group, even though it is only one single KMZ file.

I wish to edit some of these layers, and make new ones.

The issue is, when I come to export the KMZ after editing it seems like I can only export one layer at a time to KML. So I can open up a multi layered KMZ file in QGIS3, but I cannot export a multi layered (single file) KMZ file from QGIS3, I can only export single KMLs.

I wish to have one file which I can send to people to open up in Google Earth.

Is there a way to export multiple layers to KMZ in QGIS3? Or is there a work around where I can export each KML layer and then somehow combine them outside of QGIS3 to get me a KMZ layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a work around, if you simply zip multiple KMLs into one KMZ, google earth will only read the first KML file it finds within the KMZ.

A work around is to combine the KML files into one single KML file within the KMZ, this can be done by opening up the files in notepad++ and editing them following this example:

```
So instead of: 
<kml><document>blah</document></kml> 
<kml><document>hbla</document></kml> 
<kml><document>ahbl</document></kml> 
<kml><document>lahb</document></kml> 

you have 
<kml><document>blah 
hbla 
ahbl 
lahb</document></kml> 

Where ~blah is whatever stuff is in-between those broad tags.
```

quoted from:
https://www.gps-data-team.com/pda-gps-navigation/topic/318.html
(see second post)

It would be great not to do this manually, if anyone knows of a tool which can do this, please post in comments. I may write one at some stage and post it (if I end up having to create many files like this)

Answer (score 2):

You can't export KMZ files directly from QGIS. Export them separately to KML files, then zip them to a zip archive. After that just open with Notepad++ (or other software) and simply save as .kmz format. Now it will work as a single KMZ file.