# QGIS Export multiple layers to KMZ format without loosing styling properties

Tags: qgis, export, style, kmz

I have several separate layers with various styling.
I would like to export them in the KMZ format but as one file.
A similar problem was raised here:

[Exporting multiple shapefile layers from QGIS3 to one KMZ file](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/326914/exporting-multiple-shapefile-layers-from-qgis3-to-one-kmz-file/326965)
and here

[How to export multiple Shapefiles to one KML file in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22629/how-to-export-multiple-shapefiles-to-one-kml-file-in-qgis)

To be honest I am not convinced about merging the layers yet in QGIS as well as zipping them first and merging later.

I've tried to use the  layer2kmz plugin, but it seems to export just one layer. Moreover, it doesn't tolerate the rule-based styling.
Anyhow the result in Google Earth looks nice:

[image]

I tried a different way by saving my job as the geo package layer, then by using

https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/geopackage-to-kmz

the MyGeodata cloud converter I was able to combine all the layers, although without styling at all.

Is there any way to export multiple layers from QGIS to KMZ format without losing the styling?

Answer (score 1):

Exporting one layer to KMZ without losing the styling works very fine if I use [mmqgis](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/mmqgis/).

As it says in the [tool's description](https://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/), it is accessible with Python. So it must be possible to export all your layers with a script. I did not try this though.

Comment: MMQGIS exports nice KML files I agree, but it's the KML export NOT KMZ.

Comment: Easy workaround.  Add kml to Google Earth and then save as kmz?

Comment: Yes, It's a good workaround but not necessarily for 20+ layers. Is there something, i.e. Python could do?